How can I stop Acrobat Reader from giving an error trying to mysteriously access an unloaded removable D: drive?
For a long time now, whenever I cause Acrobat Reader to launch, before it does anything else, it gives me this error message:

Each of the buttons (including the close button) result in simply dismissing the message and nothing else.  Then the same error message pops up again immediately.  Dismissing it a second time lets the main window come up normally.
The next time the program launches, the same error-message two-step happens again.  And the next time,  And the next.  Forever.
Things I tried to no avail:

Clearing the recent documents list inside the application
Repairing its installation via the installer
Searching for "harddisk5\dr5" in the registry (no results found)

Next, I tried looking up "Disk 5" in Disk Management, and it turns out this is a removable drive slot for something or other which has been assigned drive letter D:.  I tried removing/changing that letter assignment.  This took away the error message!  But… putting it back to D: brings the errors back.
Playing with it a bit more, I found that having any removable drive assigned to letter D: without having anything inserted into it gives these errors.  No drive D: at all means no errors; D: with a medium loaded means no errors.  Other drive letters have no bearing, loaded or not.
Then I tried searching for "D:" in some Adobe-looking areas of the registry, but no dice.
How can I get Acrobat to stop trying to get something from a drive D: when nothing's in it?


Not an answer, but a work-around: use another app which would not be troubled by an unplugged drive. Acrobat Reader is far larger and more complex than most Win 7 PC's can handle well. Try a lightweight app like Sumatra PDF. 2. In any event, consider getting off Win 7, which is dangerous to use on the web. There is no more support for Win 7 security.

